# How to convert Postgres Hstore data type to Snowflake Object or Variant

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hstore

I am migrating a Postgres DB to Snowflake and facing the next problem. My input is a `csv` file stored in `s3`, which has the data of a Postgres table. I want to store a Postgres `HSTORE` field as an Snowflake `Object` or `Variant`. To simplify the problem we could imagine the next query that contains an hstore field after read our csv data from s3 that looks like: `'"User__id"=>"31486183"'` and I need a format like `'{"User__id":"31486183"}'` which is understood by Snowflake as a `JSON`. For example:

```
select parse_json('"User__id"=>"31486183"')
```

throw the following error.

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 28 unexpected
> '=>'. syntax error line 1 at position 28 unexpected '=>'.

We want to transform that expression into this other:

```
select parse_json('{"User__id":"31486183"}')
```

> { "User__id": "31486183" }

The only workaround that I have found is convert the `HSTORE` field in the Postgres side with the function `hstore_to_json` but I can't use this approach to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

A work around that I found but I would like to avoid is convert the format manually:

```
select parse_json(CONCAT('{',REPLACE('"User__id"=>"31486183"','=>',':'),'}'));
```

> { "User__id": "31486183" }

We can create a function with this logic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERT_HSTORE_TO_JSON(str STRING) RETURNS VARIANT AS 'select PARSE_JSON(CONCAT(\'{\',REPLACE(str,\'=>\',\':\'),\'}\'))';
```

And use it in a cleaner way (but not more efficient):

```
select CONVERT_HSTORE_TO_JSON('"User__id"=>"31486183"');
```

and access to our field as a JSON field:

```
select CONVERT_HSTORE_TO_JSON('"User__id"=>"31486183"'):"User__id";
```

> "31486183"